# data is saved twice to the database

Tags: php, yii

Here is my code:

```
public function actionPostTest()
{

    if(isset($_POST['Test']))
    {
        $model = new Test();
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Test'];
        if($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect('postTest');
        }
    }

    $this->render('posttest', array('model'=>new Test()));
}
```

This is saving the data which coming from a form twice to the database.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please add `CVarDumper::dump($_POST) ` before `if` statement and let me know.

Comment: @AliMasudianPour it is array()...but i changed the ajaxvalidation a little bit and it is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling ajax validation.

Set `enableAjaxValidation` to `false` in that view.

Actually there POST happens two times. First Ajax validation and second form submit. You can confirm it by using httpfox in firefox.

Comment: @Harikrishnan...you are right...but i needed that ajax validation and changed it a little and it is working fine now. Thanks)

Comment: sorry bro) I am new here...dont know all the details)

Answer (score 0):

> You can try by this

```
$model = new Test();
if(isset($_POST['Test']))
{       
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Test'];
    if($model->save())
    {
        unset($_POST['Test']);
        $this->redirect('postTest');
    }
}
```