# Records saving twice using mozilla firefox but not in google chrome - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I'm working on membership module. And, found that data saving twice for `membership_record` table.

What I'm doing is: After calculating total amount, tax etc. I'm saving it and redirecting it to payment gateway URL. From there, response coming to my controller function **checkout()**, where data is entering twice.

```
public function actionSubscription(){
  ..
  ..
  if($modelMemberships->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    /*
     * Ajax Validation Code
     */


    $validMembership = $modelMemberships->validate(['addTeamMember','is_free_trial']);
    if($validMembership){
      $postMemberships = Yii::$app->request->post('Membership');
      .
      .
      if($modelMemberships->save()){
        $redirectURL = Yii::$app->params['_URL'].'memberships/checkout?id='.$modelMemberships->getId();
        return $this->redirect($redirectURL); //This is redirecting to checkout function.
      }
    }

  }
}


public function actionCheckout($id){
  $payment_status = "Y";
  if($payment_status == "Y"){
    foreach($modelUsers as $modelUser){
      $modelMembershipUsers = new MembershipUsers();
      $modelMembershipUsers->membership_id = $modelMemberships->getId();
      $modelMembershipUsers->save();
    }

    //Update UC Settings
    if($modelUCSettings = UCSettings::findOne($UCSettingsId)){
      $modelUCSettings->updated_at = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
      $modelUCSettings->save(false);
    }

    return $this->redirect(['@web/memberships/receipt?id='.$id]);
  }
}
```

And, there is no code duplication. So, from no where this code will get executed until it is redirected from **subscription()** function.

I don't know why data is saving twice only in `membership_records` table.

I Checked [data is saved twice to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812514/data-is-saved-twice-to-the-database). But, the answer provided doesn't resolved my problem.

***Adding to it:*** In google chrome, there is no duplicate records. But, by using mozilla firefox, data is saving twice.

Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say if there's `. .` -  missing code in `actionSubsciption()`.

Comment: @Yupik: Relevant codes are entered only. Believe in me, there is no such lines of code written which will cause harm.

Comment: One thing i learned here: dont trust in 'believe me'. If this action is responsible for duplicate records, we need all code inside, otherwise we can just guessing.

Comment: Using Ajax Validation?

Comment: Hi @InsaneSkull, I think No.Because, If it happens also, then membership record will also get duplicated. But, only membership_records table having multiple record. It is happening only in mozilla not in chrome. Brother, you can help me. You helped me so many times. This time too, please.

Comment: Have you enabled Ajax Validation in form? Add full controller code. Probably your form submitted twice.